# connection timeout when connecting to a remote postgresql database

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am facing this problem: I have a program that loops the following:

- connect to a postgresql database
- print a count number
- close the connection

code is as follow:

```
int i = 0;
    while(true){

        IConnection conn = ((ConnectionHelper)HelperFactory.getInstance().getHelper("ConnectionHelper")).getConnection("psql");

        if(conn != null && conn.connect()){
            conn.close();
            System.out.println(i++);
        }
    }
```

I connect to psql db by jdbc, something like this:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":5432/" + database, 
                                            user, password);
```

the conn.connect() returns true if it can successfully connect to the database
(tested, I can retrieve data from it)

But i get the following result:

0
1
2
.
.
.
3919
3920
3921
3922

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
```

at the last loop the program stuck at trying to connect to psql til timeout. Any help?

Comment: Can you access it using other client like PGAdmin ? Server is rechable ?

Comment: Any reason why you are opening and closing the connection on every iteration?

Comment: @Jigar Joshi I can successfully query on the first 3xxx connection

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds It is just a simulation

Answer (score 1):

Related to the exception message host or/and port where postgres is running not equals to the host or/and port what you put to the connect address, check it and you will find problem.

---

And yes, your server cannot be reachable, some firewals and so on, check it too.

Comment: I am sure the server is reachable for first 3xxx connection. I can query on the db and successfully get the result. The problem is it somehow cannot connectable after thousands of connection opened and closed

Comment: Can you look at the poll connection on server side, I mean how many connection are opened and not closed from server?

Comment: @Sergii Zagriichuk This is the first time am i using postgresql and i am not familiar with it. I don't know how to check the existing connection of psql. Any help?

Comment: One sec, I will try to remember :) and will write.

Comment: try next sql query SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;

Comment: I now found that if i let the loop goes on, after some iterations, it can reconnect successfully, then this problem happened again.

Comment: Have you found two connections and still received errors? You have to run this query in runtime of execution your code, just this can shows you all scope of connections, because after stop execution process scope count of connections can be changed. Add execution of this query before close connection and print count to console.

Comment: The two connections are SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity; and one irrelevant connection. If i repeatedly exec SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;, sometimes i can find a connection that is the created by this looping program. So, my program should be able to open and close the connections correctly

Comment: Yes, but your program cannot,so, the way with pool connections is clear, the next way of investigation is try to test on one machine, I mean  sql server and your program the same macine, and please write what is result ?

Comment: I try and test on one machine, that error doesn't happened. Is this just a stupid network problem?

Comment: It is not a stupid :) it is just a network problem, I will investigate some steps and will write you.

Comment: What hosts have you trusted? I mean what is written in your postgresql.conf and  pg_hba.conf ?

Comment: I have added the ip of the looping program hosting machine to pg_hba.conf with keyword 'trust' and set listen_addresses = '*' in postgresql.conf. By the way, is there a way to set a range of ips in pg_hba.conf. By now, i have to write one record for each ip